# How do you program a large table and search the minimum in each column?

Tags: list-manipulation

How does one program a table (2d list) with a huge amount of data which can be done manually. For example: the rows go from -1 to 1 by step 0.0005 and the columns go from -3 to 3 by step 1. Subsequently, how does one search the minimum value in each column and print the pair of values (column's value,row's value) what is  corresponding to the column's minimum value?

Answer (score 6):

```
(* some dummy data *)
test = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 5}];

(* do your thing *)
stuff = Block[{t = Transpose@test, mins},
              mins = Min /@ t;
              Transpose[{SparseArray[Unitize[t - mins], Automatic, 1]["NonzeroPositions"], mins}]];

(* show results *)
Column[{test // MatrixForm, stuff // MatrixForm}, Left, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: While this is a correct answer this is obviously way over the head of the poster who is seemingly not even aware of the existence of `Table`. With all due respect of course, I don't think this answer will help him very much.

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries  +1 but I also upvoted ciao also. Posting here means posting to all the members not just the OP. His answer did help me as did yours. So if you have a more advanced solution just let it rip and post it.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to do this in Mathematica and you can use many programming styles. Mathematica shines when using the functional programming style, but my guess is that's a bit early for you. So the answer below will refrain from most advanced stuff.

First, we'll need some function that fills your table, depending on the column and row values. Since you didn't specify anything here's a random one. You can use any function of your own instead.

```
f[row_, col_] := row col - row^2 col^3
```

Now, let's fill a table with data:

```
data = Table[f[row, col], {row, -1, 1, 0.0005}, {col, -3, 3}];
```

Finally, find the minimum values of all the columns (explanation follows):

```
Table[
   min = Min[data[[All, c]]];
   {Position[data[[All, c]], min, 1][[1, 1]], c},
   {c, 1, Length[data[[1]]]}
 ]
(* {{2112, 1}, {2251, 2}, {3001, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}} *)
```

Explanation:

We loop over all columns, using loop variable `c`. Within the `Table` the first step is:

```
 min = Min[data[[All, c]]];
```

`data[[All, c]]` means "all rows of column c". This is a one-dimensional list. `Min` finds the minimum value of this list.

```
{Position[data[[All, c]], min, 1][[1, 1]], c},
```

Next, we use `Position` to find this minimum value and get the position. The argument 1 means we're interested in the first one. Since `Position` returns a list of positions we've to pick one, the first coordinate of the list in this case, and from this the first number. `[[1,1]]` accomplishes this. Together with `{... ,c`} we now have a `{r, c}` pair that will end up in the resulting list of the `Table` (because they are the last of the set of functions in the `Table` function).